# Bind Clipboard JS event to button after using jQuery load/Ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard.js

I am using the ClipboardJS library to copy text that is attached to a button using the `data-clipboard-text` attribute. I am also using jQuery's `.load()` function to dynamically pull in HTML content. This content includes copies of the **Copy** text buttons. When the 'fresh' buttons are loaded using jQuery, the buttons no longer have an event bound to them. I have attached my current working code below.

Is there a way to re-bind the events to the buttons after the dynamic content is loaded? A vanilla JS solution would be preferable.

**jQuery load function**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {    
    // AJAX .load function for sendout post content
    e( ".sendout-link" ).click(function() {
        var post_url = e( this ).attr( "href" );
        e( "#sendout-container" ).html( '<div class="loading">Loading...</div>' );
        e( "#sendout-container" ).load( post_url, function( response, status, xhr ) {
            if ( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                e( "#sendout-container" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**ClipboardJS code**

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.copy-button');
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(btns);
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    e.trigger.textContent = 'URL Copied';
    e.trigger.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        e.trigger.textContent = 'Copy URL';
        e.trigger.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, 5000);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error('Action:', e.action);
    console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the events during the dynamic `load()` process.

```
function bindCopy(){
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.copy-button');
    var clipboard = new ClipboardJS(btns);
    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        e.trigger.textContent = 'URL Copied';
        e.trigger.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            e.trigger.textContent = 'Copy URL';
            e.trigger.removeAttribute('disabled');
        }, 5000);
    });
    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error('Action:', e.action);
        console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {    
    // AJAX .load function for sendout post content
    e( ".sendout-link" ).click(function() {
        var post_url = e( this ).attr( "href" );
        e( "#sendout-container" ).html( '<div class="loading">Loading...</div>' );
        e( "#sendout-container" ).load( post_url, function( response, status, xhr ) {
            if ( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                e( "#sendout-container" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
            }else{
               bindCopy(); //each time content is loaded
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    bindCopy(); //first time
});
```